# How would I scale multiple spans using SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestringbuilder

I have this working, but redundant, code:

```
feedbackView.text = SpannableStringBuilder()
    .scale(.6f) { italic { append(getString(R.string.suggestion_prefix)) } }
    .scale(.6f) { append("\n\n") }
    .scale(.6f) { bold { append(s) } }
```

How would I refactor it so there is only one call to `.scale()`?

When I try this, only the first string is scaled:

```
feedbackView.text = SpannableStringBuilder()
    .scale(.6f, { italic { append(getString(R.string.suggestion_prefix)) } })
    .append("\n\n")
    .bold { append(s) }
```

I have not been able to figure out the syntax to include everything in the lambda argument to `scale()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put everything inside one scale lambda.

```
feedbackView.text = SpannableStringBuilder()
    .scale(.6f) {
        italic { append(getString(R.string.suggestion_prefix)) }
        .append("\n\n")
        .bold { append(s) }
     }
```

Comment: It looks so obvious now!